# Why when rotating an object on the y axis when running the game first the object is rotating at once by 180 degrees?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The script make the object to rotate from side to side depending on the speed and angle values.

but when I'm running the game first time the object is rotating at once by 180 degrees and then it start rotating from side to side depending on the speed and angle. but I want it to start rotating from side to side from it's original rotation 0,0,0 and not from 180.

The object before running the game the rotation of the child Pod_Weapon_L is 0,0,0

[image: original rotation]

then when running the game at the first frame the child Pod_Weapon_L rotation is changing to  0,176.51,0

[image: rotation changed on the first frame after running]

I can't figure out why it happens.

This is the script attached to the Pod_Weapon_L:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WeaponsController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float rotationSpeed = 10f;
    [SerializeField] private float rotationAngle = 45f;

    private float currentAngle;
    private bool rotateClockwise = true;

    private void Update()
    {
        // Calculate the rotation amount based on the rotation speed and time
        float rotationAmount = rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        // Update the current angle based on the rotation direction
        currentAngle += rotateClockwise ? rotationAmount : -rotationAmount;

        // Check if the current angle exceeds the specified angle limit
        if (Mathf.Abs(currentAngle) >= rotationAngle)
        {
            // Reverse the rotation direction
            rotateClockwise = !rotateClockwise;
        }

        // Apply the rotation to the object
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, currentAngle, 0f);
    }
}
```

I want it to start rotating from 0,0,0 not from 0,176.51,0

Comment: Try setting currentAngle to the actual y value in Start.  It seems like the child has a rotation already, and when you start at 0 it removes that initial rotation.  The values you see in the inspector are local, so they take the parent object into account.  When you are setting the rotation via `transform.rotation` you are in world space, not local.

Comment: solution is to change the rotation of the transform to localRotation: transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, currentAngle, 0f);

Answer (score 1):

Initiate the object programmatically in the first frame.

```
public class WeaponsController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float rotationSpeed = 10f;
    [SerializeField] private float rotationAngle = 45f;

    private float currentAngle;
    private bool rotateClockwise = true;
    private bool initiated = false;

    private void Update()
    {
        if(!initiated){
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, 0f);
        }
        // Calculate the rotation amount based on the rotation speed and time
        float rotationAmount = rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        // Update the current angle based on the rotation direction
        currentAngle += rotateClockwise ? rotationAmount : -rotationAmount;

        // Check if the current angle exceeds the specified angle limit
        if (Mathf.Abs(currentAngle) >= rotationAngle)
        {
            // Reverse the rotation direction
            rotateClockwise = !rotateClockwise;
        }

        // Apply the rotation to the object
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, currentAngle, 0f);
    }
}
```